# ImportError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python, unit-testing, package

I am working on a project with following tree structure:

```
Project
  app
    main.py
    svg_to_png.py
    __init__.py
    tests
       __init__.py
       unittests
          basic_test.py
          __init__.py
```

I am importing app functions to basic_tests by using

```
from app.main import *
```

when I execute the `basic_test.py`, it gives the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

Also, while in the top directory of the project, when I type `python3 -m app.main`, the program executes for a while, then gives the same import error at the following line

`from app.svg_to_png import do_svg2png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import from higher up the directory structure that way. One way to do it would be

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../..")
from main import *
```

For the second import, you'd want to do

```
from .svg_to_png import do_svg2png
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) section of the Python documentation specifically